# WP Bool not sticking

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

i have a music playing app, which i'm trying to create a repeat function in.
If i set the bool manually every performs as should, but if i use the button on the main page it doesn't.

Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
public static bool repeat
    {

   get {return AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton;}
   set {repeat = value;}
    }

    private void RepeatButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {                     
        if (repeat == false)
        {             
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton);               
            AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton = true;
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/repeaton.png", UriKind.Relative));
            RepeatButton.Background = brush;
        }
        else if (repeat == true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton);
            AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton = false;
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/repeatoff.png" UriKind.Relative));
            RepeatButton.Background = brush;
        }
    }
```

Audio Player.cs

```
  public static bool repeaton = false;

    protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
    {
        ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("liveTile".ToString()));
        switch (playState)
        {
            case PlayState.TrackEnded:
                if (repeaton == false)
                {
                    if (player.Track != null)
                        MyPlayer.currentTrackNumber = FindTrack(player.Track);
                    player.Track = MyPlayer.GetNextTrack();
                }
                else if (repeaton == true)
                {
                    if (player.Track != null)
                        MyPlayer.currentTrackNumber = FindTrack(player.Track);
                    player.Track = MyPlayer.GetRepeatTrack();
                }
                break;
```

the debugger shows the value changing, but the player ignores the changes.
if i manually set repeaton works fine, for the life of me i cannot get it to work, please help.

Comment: try making it a non-static property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong (seems like it should not even work at all):

```
public static bool repeat
{
    get {return AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton;}
    set {repeat = value;} //You set value to *this* property???
}
```

Instead, you should `set` using the same value, like this:

```
public static bool repeat
{
    get {return AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton;}
    set {AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton= value;}
}
```

**And**
if you are going to do this, use `repeat` everywhere and *not* use `AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton`

(or ditch the `repeat` and only use `AudioPlaybackAgent1.AudioPlayer.repeaton`).